# How to start a Tomcat 8.5 server on VSC using Community Server Connector extension

Tags: java, jsp, visual-studio-code, tomcat

I'm trying to set up a Tomcat Server on VSC (since it couldn't work on IntelliJ because I don't have the ultimate edition) but I have no experience (and neither do my colleagues) with Community Server Connector. All our documentation is written for Tomcat For Java extension, but since it's deprecated we have to use Community Server Connector. I've done all the necessary steps (like LDAP certificates, changes to server.xml etc) so it should be working...right?

Once I try to start the server I get
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache

We don't really have a clue where we could solve this, we looked a lot online but nothing really seems to work. If someone has an idea where to look and/or what settings to change please help!

If you need more information, just leave a message

Looked over the documentation steps to see if I missed something
Tried out all (I think) of the options within the extension
Searched online for solutions
Asked colleagues but they couldn't find it either

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you could provide the tomcat you are using and the steps you did and the link you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the [**Community Server Connectors**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector) extension.

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Servers: Add Local Servers...`.

[image]

In the pop-up explorer window, select the decompressed tomcat root directory (that is, the value of the system environment variable **CATALINA_HOME**).

[image]

Confirm that the information is correct and click `Finish`.

[image]

Select the generated `war` package, right-click and select `Run on Server`.

[image]

In the **SERVERS** view, right-click on the *tomcat* service and select `Server Actions...` --> `Show in browser...` --> `http://localhost:8080/demo/`.

[image]

The browser will open and display the project page.

[image]

Comment: how to implement hot reload for jsp file, css, js?

Comment: I performed the same steps but getting an error when trying to start the server-  Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Apache
Can you please suggest any fix?

Answer (score 0):

in tomcat-users.xml (in your tomcat config folder) make sure you have the roles setup. adding this should solve your problem

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui" />
  <role rolename="admin" />
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui" />
</tomcat-users>
```