# Webapp missing in Tomcat webapps folder - Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, tomcat, web-applications

I have a Java maven project, which is corretly built and .war correctly created.

I installed Visual Studio Code extension called Community Server Connector, where I added my apache-tomcat-8.5.50 folder with my Tomcat 8.5 server.
Then I put in this Tomcat a deployment - the .war file of my project.

[image]

When I want to run the server, everything seems to be good, but the project doesn't appear in the webapps folder of the Tomcat and the page of the webapp in browser is returning error 404.

Comment: How are you running the server? Is your tomcat configured correctly? You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74397713/19133920) maybe it helps.