# Unable to Add Local Server after installing Community Servers Connectors in

Tags: vscode-extensions

I wanted to setup Apache Tomcat in my VSC editor for some Java web development, but the extension was deprecated.

It suggested installing the Community Servers Connectors instead and I did. I also followed some steps from the answers here [How to start a Tomcat 8.5 server on VSC using Community Server Connector extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388409/how-to-start-a-tomcat-8-5-server-on-vsc-using-community-server-connector-extensi)

When I tried typing in >Servers: Add Local Server, there was an error saying "Unable to detect any server: Extension backend error - there are no rsp providers currently". I also tried another version of the community extension to 0.25.7 but still got the same error.

I don't understand what I'm missing. Can anyone help me with this problem? Much appreciated!