Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache when running Tomcat server in VSCode
I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my project on Tomcat server within VSCode. Every time I attempt to start the server, I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Apache
When I click on run on server
How to start a Tomcat 8.5 server on VSC using Community Server Connector extension
I followed this post to setup Tomcat.
Here's some additional context and details:
I'm using Community Server Connectors v0.26.16, Tomcat v8.5 and JDK 1.6
My project is a Java web application.
I have also added java_home and cataline_home in env variable path.
I've tried searching for solutions online but haven't been able to find a fix that works for me. Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388409/how-to-start-a-tomcat-8-5-server-on-vsc-using-community-server-connector-extensi/74397713#74397713

I am having the same problem TomCat 9 with Java 8. Hope there is a solution with VS Code - Community Server Connector.  Error: Could not find or load main class Files
